# for loop wont work in a function inside react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import React from 'react'; 
const RowArray=()=>{
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Row Array</h1>
        </div>
    )
}; 
const chunk_array = (list, integer)=>{
     
        let temp_arr = list;
        console.log('chunks',list,'integer',integer);
        const list_of_chunks = [];
        const iteration = Math.ceil(+list.length/+integer);
        // list.map(x => {console.log(x,"map")})
        for (let i;i< iteration ;i++ ){
            console.log(i);
            let temp_chunk = temp_arr.splice(6, temp_arr.length);
            list_of_chunks.push(temp_chunk); 
        }; 
        return list_of_chunks;
}

const TableArray=({details})=>{
    const data = chunk_array(details);
    console.log('data', data);
    return(
        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <RowArray/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default TableArray;
```

the for loop in function chunk array won't work, supported as no i was logged in the console. I understand in jsx for loop may not work, I believe I define the function in pure javascript enviroment, so why do you think it is?

Console.log(i) doesn't log anything, as in the function skipped for loop line

Comment: can you log your `iteration` variable outside the `for` loop and see what's the value

Comment: See if you are getting any runtime errors in the console? Because, you are passing single argument `details` but in the `chunk_array` you are expecting two parameters `list` and `integer`. I think your code is breaking at `Math.ceil(+list.length/+integer)` because `integer` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

you haven't initialized the value of `i` in the `for` loop

```
 for (let i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
  // your code
 }
```

`chunk_array` function expects two arguments and you're only passing one argument details

Comment: OF COURSE! have not been using for loop in a very long time since knowing for of / for in. Thanks there!